# Skip value must be non-negative, but received: -1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

i am trying to execute a command from pymongo below query like below

```
oid = json.dumps(collection name.find_one({}, skip=doc_count -1)['_id'], default=json_util.default)
```

when i try to execute this i am getting below error

```
OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response, pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Skip value must be non-negative, but received: -1
```

Note this is a query to execute a mongo command. can any one help me on this

Comment: probably `doc_count` variable sometime is 0